# Telerik Report avoid datasource execution if not required

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-reporting

My application is multilingual application. In my application, I have created a report which has 2 data source. Both call same procedures and fetch same data. The difference only is based on culture, the data will be filled and table will be displayed.

It is working fine. But the problem I am facing is, though I have applied condition to display table based on culture, it is executing both data source. That is I have one unnecessary database call.

Is there any alternative to solve this?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If your data source comes from SQL, I believe you can do this in a stored procedure with a report parameter. (I assume your tables are in the same database, but you can adjust accordingly)

I will use the AdventureWorks database, and my sp selects the "Name" column from a given table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test] @table nvarchar(100) as 
BEGIN
    declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT Name FROM ' + @table
    exec SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
END;
```

Then, configure the datasource to execute the stored procedure, taking in a report parameter for @table. In my example, reportParameter="Person.AddressType" or "Person.ContactType" will give different results.

In your case, change the reportParameter according to culture. Now you will only need one table instead of two as well.